# C# Code porting to Python not the same result

Tags: python, c#

so I got into Python recently I have a project I'm trying to port from C# to Python,

To learn more on how python works but I ran into this trouble,

I'm having trouble trying to get the same output as the C# code.

C# Code: outputs the length as `46`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json =
        "{\"id\":1,\"token\":\"testing\",\"type\":3,\"cmd\":1}";
    send_request(json, 3, 1);

    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void encrypt_decrypt(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] numArray = {250, 158, 179};

    for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; ++index)
    {
        if (data[index] != numArray[index % numArray.Length])
            data[index] = (byte) (data[index] ^ (uint) numArray[index % numArray.Length]);
    }
}

public static void send_request(string str, byte type, byte cmd)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] array = new byte[bytes.Length + 2];

    array[0] = type;
    array[1] = cmd;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, array, 2, bytes.Length);

    encrypt_decrypt(array);
    send_message(array);
}

private static void send_message(byte[] message)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[message.Length + 1];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(message, 0, array, 0, message.Length);
    array[message.Length] = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
}
```

Python Code: outputs the length as `44`

```
def main():
    json = "{\"id\":1,\"token\":\"testing\",\"type\":3,\"cmd\":1}"
    send_request(json, 3, 1)

def encrypt_decrypt(data):
    r_list = [250, 158, 179]
    arr = bytearray(r_list)

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] is not arr[i % len(arr)]:
            data[i] = (data[i] ^ arr[i % len(arr)])


def send_request(str, type, cmd):
    print('Sending ' + str)
    str_bytes = bytes(str, 'utf-8')
    array = bytearray(len(str_bytes) + 2)
    array[0] = type
    array[1] = cmd
    array[0:2 + len(str_bytes)] = str_bytes
    encrypt_decrypt(array)
    send_message(array)


def send_message(message):
    array = bytearray(len(message) + 1)
    pos = 0
    array[pos:pos + len(message)] = message
    array[len(message)] = 0
    print(len(array))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

For the C#-part, that's because you're declaring the array with the length of 46. (`json.Length` is initially 43, after adding +2 in `send_request`, the size of `array` will be 45.)

Note `array = new byte[message.Length + 1]`. At this point, `message.Length` is 45. Thus, adding +1 results in 46 as seen in `Console.WriteLine(array.Length);`.

For python, just a guess: could it be that pythons `print(len(array))` only prints the length of the actual filled values?